# rails form_for create new entry instead of updating

Tags: ruby-on-rails, form-for

I am using form_for in order to create a new entry.

In the controller I set:

```
def create_ab_campaign
  @campaign = Campaign.find_by(id: params[:id],  account_id: current_account.id)
  @campaign_id = params[:id]
end
```

In the view I do:

```
<%= form_for (@campaign), :url => {:controller => "campaigns", :action => "create_new_ab_campaign"} do |f| %>
<div class="form-group">
<%= f.label :name, "name", class: "control-label" %>
<%= f.text_field :name, class: "form-control", placeholder: "name" %>
</div>
<%= f.submit "Save Settings" %>
```

On submit I want **to create a new entry instead of updating** the existing one.

I did the following in the controller:

```
def create_ab_campaign_new
  @campaign_new = Campaign.new(create_a_new_ab_campaign)
   if @campaign_new.save
    redirect_to(:controller =>"campaigns", :action =>"index")
   else
    redirect_to(:action =>"new")
   end
end

private
  def create_a_new_ab_campaign
    params.require(:campaign).permit(:name)
  end
```

I get the following:
NoMethodError in CampaignsController#update

It tries still to use the update instead of "create_a_new_ab_campaign"

I used the update for updating records - this works all fine.

```
def update
  @campaign = Campaign.find_by(id:params[:id], account_id: current_account.id)
  @new = create_new_campaign
  if @campaign.update_attributes(@new)
    redirect_to(:controller =>"campaigns", :action =>"index")
  else
    render 'edit'
  end
end
```

But as described instead of an update/edit I want to do another case and create a new entry out of the record.

Thanks a lot for your help!

UPDATE:

Full error log:

NoMethodError in CampaignsController#update
undefined method `update_attributes' for nil:NilClass

Extracted source (around line #124):
122
123
124
125
126
127

```
@new = create_new_campaign
@new[:page_type].delete_if{ |x| x.empty? }
if @campaign.update_attributes(@new)
  redirect_to(:controller =>"campaigns", :action =>"index")
else
  render 'edit'
```

Rails.root: /Users/sschindler/demostore

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/controllers/campaigns_controller.rb:124:in `update'

Update routes

Routes:

post "campaigns/create_new_ab_campaign"

get "campaigns/create_new_ab_campaign"

post "/campaigns/:id/edit" => "campaigns#edit"

get "/campaigns/:id/edit" => "campaigns#edit"

post "/campaigns/create_ab_campaign" => "campaigns#create_ab_campaign"

get "/campaigns/create_ab_campaign" => "campaigns#create_ab_campaign"

post "/campaigns/:id" => "campaigns#edit"

post "/campaigns/:id" => "campaigns#new"

get "/campaigns/:id" => "campaigns#edit"

get 'campaigns/show'

get 'campaigns/index'

post '/campaigns/edit'

get '/campaigns/edit'

Comment: Please post the full error stacktrace.

Comment: You got lot of typos in the code.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming your `create_ab_campaign` is your new route and `create_ab_campaign_new` is your post route. Although i am little confused because you have a `params[:id]` value in `#create_ab_campaign`

From the looks of it though, your form is trying to update because you're passing `form_for` an already created campaign variable: `@campaign = Campaign.find_by(...)`

rails `form_for` will check if the object is an instance in your db or if its just a new Model. if its already been created, it will `PATCH` to your update route; if its a new Model (but not created) it will `POST` to your create route.

in your `#new` route, you need to assign `@campaign` to `Campaign.new(account_id:current_account.id)` instead of finding one thats already been made.

**Update**
Based on your comments, you want to duplicate a model, change some of the fields and save it as a new record. in that case, you'd want to send the id of the campaign model that you want to copy to the form, so you can retrieve it in your create route, use model.dup, modify it with params, then save.

```
def create_ab_campaign
  @campaign = Campaign.new
  @campaign_id = params[:id]
end
```

add hidden field to form

```
<%= form_for (@campaign), :url => {:controller => "campaigns", :action => "create_new_ab_campaign"} do |f| %>
<div class="form-group">
<%= hidden_field_tag :campaign_id, @campaign_id
<%= f.label :name, "name", class: "control-label" %>
<%= f.text_field :name, class: "form-control", placeholder: "name" %>
</div>
<%= f.submit "Save Settings" %>
```

Create route
dup the campaign, make modifications, and check validity. Be sure not to have uniqueness validations on this model or youll run into a bit of trouble

```
def create_ab_campaign_new
  @campaign_new = Campaign.find(params[:campaign_id]).dup
  @campaign_new.update(create_a_new_ab_campaign)
   if @campaign_new.save
    redirect_to(:controller =>"campaigns", :action =>"index")
   else
    redirect_to(:action =>"new")
   end
end
```

Comment: PhilVarg, thanks a lot. Here is the route post "campaigns/create_new_ab_campaign" 
  get "campaigns/create_new_ab_campaign" 

  post "/campaigns/:id/edit" => "campaigns#edit"
  get "/campaigns/:id/edit" => "campaigns#edit"
 
  post "/campaigns/create_ab_campaign" => "campaigns#create_ab_campaign"
  get "/campaigns/create_ab_campaign" => "campaigns#create_ab_campaign"
  post "/campaigns/:id" => "campaigns#edit"
  post "/campaigns/:id" => "campaigns#new"
  get "/campaigns/:id" => "campaigns#edit"
  get 'campaigns/show'
  get 'campaigns/index'

Comment: I wanted to use the information of an existing Campaing to create a new one. The Background is: I want to create an AB Test for the same Campaing and modify one thing in it. It should then be saved as a new campaign.

Comment: Yes, I cloned it now first and then edit it, since it always tries to update it directly.  Thanks a lot for help!!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're mixing your VERBS

```
`post "campaigns/create_new_ab_campaign"`
```

is a post and

`= form_for (@campaign), :url => {:controller => "campaigns", :action => "create_new_ab_campaign"} do |f|`

is a PUT. Try change to

in route.rb:

`match 'create_new_ab_campaign', to 'campaigns#create_new_ab_campaign', via: :post`

and then

`=form_for(@campaign), url: :create_new_ab_campaign, method: 'POST' do |f|`

*Basically* If you call form_for on a new object, the form submit method defaults to a  `POST` and if you using on an existing object, the form submit method defaults to a `PUT/PATCH`. This is why it keeps looking for update. To change this add the `method` keyword to your form builder.

further reading: http://www.restapitutorial.com/lessons/httpmethods.html

Comment: Thanks a lot!! for the link. To get around the problem, I cloned the Campaing first now, and then edit it (). But I will check on the method keyword as well!

Comment: Sounds good for now. Not to be a sticker, but keep it RESTful. POST = new record, PUT/PATCH = update existing record.